# attributes delegation when extending component using Facelets

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

When implementing a custom facelets component which extends some existing component, it is pretty common that your custom component accepts the same attributes as the component being extended.
For example extended h:inputText could be as following:

```
<ui:composition>
<custom:decorate styleClass="input">
    <h:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value}" required="#{required}"
                 styleClass="#{styleClass}" disabled="#{disabled}" rendered="#{rendered}"
                 converterMessage="#{converterMessage}"
                 requiredMessage="#{requiredMessage}"
                 validatorMessage="#{validatorMessage}" onchange="#{onchange}"
                 style="#{style}">
        <ui:insert/>
    </h:inputText>
</custom:decorate></ui:composition>
```

The goal is to allow component's client to use extended version in the same way as the component being extended.
The example above has the following gaps:

1. id attribute is required, passing no value will not force auto id generation.
2. converterMessage, requiredMessage, validatorMessage, ... - pretty the same as 'id' attribute these attributes should have special meaning if not provided by client
3. disabled, rendered, and other boolean attributes - if client does not provide value then '#{attributeName}' is resolved to 'false'.
4. action and actionListener - for action source components, facelets are trying to evaluate value specified by client as 'ValueExpression', not as 'MethodExpression'.

There are some simple straightforward solutions (for example to use c:if, c:when, etc. to handle 1-3; passing bean and actionMethodName or implement an action mapper component to handle 4), but when number of attributes is large, component's code become a hell of spaghetti code.

Maybe there are already some solid solutions available for JSF 1.2?
It will be also useful for me to see an answer with nice ideas how to implement such solution or a part of a solution.